# Error in VisualStudio 2012 when creating Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio

I receive an error in workflow designer when created new "Workflow" item in "SharePoint 2013 Empty Project" or "App for SharePoint 2013".

[image: Error in workflow designer]

An error when created new "Workflow" item in "SharePoint 2013 Empty Project":

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)
   at System.UnitySerializationHolder.GetRealObject(StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.ResolveObjectReference(ObjectHolder holder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.DesignerContract.IDesignerContract.Load(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.HostAdapter.IDesignerViewToContractHostAdapter.Load(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load(String fileName, UInt32 formatMode, Int32 readOnly)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

An error when created new "Workflow" item in "App for SharePoint 2013":

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DirectoryCatalog.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetExports>b__2(ComposablePartCatalog catalog)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__14`2.MoveNext()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InternalGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InnerCatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1& exports)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportsCore(Type type, Type metadataViewType, String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueCore[T](String contractName, ImportCardinality cardinality)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueOrDefault[T](String contractName)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExportedValueOrDefault[T]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.WorkflowDesignerExtensionManager.InternalGetExtension[T]()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.WorkflowDesignerExtensionManager.GetExtension(Type hostServiceType)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.WorkflowDesignerExtensionManager.GetExtension(String extensionTypeAssemblyQualifiedName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.GetHostService(String hostServiceTypeAssemblyQualifiedName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.HostAdapter.IProcessDesignerEventsContractToViewHostAdapter.GetHostService(String hostServiceTypeAssemblyQualifiedName)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.DesignerContract.IProcessDesignerEventsContract.GetHostService(String hostServiceTypeAssemblyQualifiedName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddInAdapter.IProcessDesignerEventsContractToViewAddInAdapter.GetHostService(String hostServiceTypeAssemblyQualifiedName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddIn.ProcessDesignerEventsAddInViewProxy.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddInView.IProcessDesignerEventsAddInView.GetHostService(String hostServiceTypeAssemblyQualifiedName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddIn.HostServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at System.Activities.Presentation.EditingContext.DefaultServiceManager.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at System.Activities.Presentation.ServiceManager.GetService[TServiceType]()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddIn.WorkflowDesignerAddIn.GetRootInstance()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddIn.WorkflowDesignerAddIn.RemoveRootSourceLocation()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddIn.WorkflowDesignerAddIn.Load(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.AddInAdapter.IDesignerContractToViewAddInAdapter.Load(String fileName)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.DesignerContract.IDesignerContract.Load(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.HostAdapter.IDesignerViewToContractHostAdapter.Load(String fileName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load(String fileName, UInt32 formatMode, Int32 readOnly)
```

Also when I try to deploy this empty workflow I received such error from visual studio:

```
Error   1   Workflow Manager Tools need to be installed to build this project.  SharePointProject3
```

Workflow Manager has already installed in my SP server.

Also I can create and deploy SP 2013 Workflow through SP Designer 2013 and the workflow successfully works on site.

*How can I resolve this issue?*

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Workflow is handled by Workflow Manager 1.0 which is dependent on
> Service Bus 1.0, you need to install the two February CU's for both
> Service Bus 1.0 & Workflow Manager 1.0:
>
> February 2013 Cumulative Update for Service Bus 1.0: [KB2799752](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36794)
>
> February 2013 Cumulative Update for Workflow Manager 1.0:
> [KB2799754](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36800)
>
> To verify the installs completed correctly, you can check the file
> versions for both products.
>
> For Service Bus, look in C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.0 for the
> Microsoft.Cloud.ServiceBus.dll. This should be version
> **2.0.30207.2.**
>
> For Workflow Manager, look in C:\Program Files\Workflow
> Manager\1.0\Workflow\Artifacts for the Microsoft.Workflow.Service.dll
> (*not* the EXE). This is the DLL that runs the workflow backend
> service. It should be version **1.0.30207.2.**

[Source](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/Updates-For-SP2013-Workflow)

Then have a try.

Comment: It still doesn't work. The same error.