# Workflow Designer in Visual Studio now crashing - can't load assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2015

I have VisualStudio 2015, and until very recently, the Worflow Designer worked, I could create workflows in VS.  I'm not sure what changed, I applied VS 2015 Update 3 back at the beginning of November, and that's the last change I know of to VS itself, and things were still working after that.

Now, when I double-click on a XAML file to edit a workflow, the tab in VS gives me the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.WorkflowExtensions,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I found this [blog post by Andrew Connell](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-workflow-designer-fails-to-load-in-visual-studio-2013), and ran the little Powershell command he has there, and it does find the DLL at the following path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\WorkflowDesigner
```

So the DLL is where it should be, as far as I can tell.  I tried his solution (close the XAML tab and re-open it), but that didn't work.  Just as in the comments on his article, I instead get the error:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been
>   added.    at
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
>   value, Boolean add)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPanesManager.OnEditorPaneRenamed(String
>   oldValue, String newValue, EditorPane editorPane)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.set_FileName(String
>   value)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Activities.EditorPane.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IPersistFileFormat.Load(String
>   fileName, UInt32 formatMode, Int32 readOnly)

I also found this [question and answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/89631/8992), and the solution there is apparently to update Workflow Manager and Service Bus on my server.  But, they are already the latest versions.

So, before I try re-installing VS, is there any way to get VS pointed back at the DLL that is in the VS Extensions folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, instead of completely re-installing Visual Studio, I manually un-installed and re-installed Office Developer Tools for VS2015, and that seems to have worked, I can now open a XAML file and see the workflow designer window.