# Visual Studio Workflow Designer - can't access properties in GetODataProperties

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I need to edit a workflow I created in VS, but now when I open the workflow in VS, I no longer have access to the specific properties in the "Get Properties" activity.

I get the current item and assign it to a Dynamic Value variable:

[image: get current item activity]

But then in the next step, when I use a `Microsoft.Activities.GetODataProperties` activity to get specific properties from the item and assign them to variables, I can see where to specify the source, but there is no longer anywhere for me to specify the properties to retrieve:

[image: get properties activity]

If I crack open the XAML file in VS Code, I can see that the properties to retrieve are still defined in the XAML, they are just not showing up in the editor in VS:

[image: workflow raw xaml]

[The last time I had a problem with Workflow Designer in VS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/203709/8992), uninstalling and reinstalling Office Developer Tools for VS2015 did the trick, but not this time.  After a reinstall, the problem persists.

Has anyone else run into this, and how did you fix it?